# ActionView::Template::Error (Missing block): while using simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, simple-form, model-associations

I created a page showing posts and if I open any particular post say "localhost:3000/newsfeeds/14".
I want to render comments and comment form in that too.
My routes are:

```
   newsfeed_comments GET    /newsfeeds/:newsfeed_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                     POST   /newsfeeds/:newsfeed_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
new_newsfeed_comment GET    /newsfeeds/:newsfeed_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_newsfeed_comment GET    /newsfeeds/:newsfeed_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
    newsfeed_comment GET    /newsfeeds/:newsfeed_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                     PATCH  /newsfeeds/:newsfeed_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     PUT    /newsfeeds/:newsfeed_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     DELETE /newsfeeds/:newsfeed_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
           newsfeeds GET    /newsfeeds(.:format)                                newsfeeds#index
                     POST   /newsfeeds(.:format)                                newsfeeds#create
        new_newsfeed GET    /newsfeeds/new(.:format)                            newsfeeds#new
       edit_newsfeed GET    /newsfeeds/:id/edit(.:format)                       newsfeeds#edit
            newsfeed GET    /newsfeeds/:id(.:format)                            newsfeeds#show
                     PATCH  /newsfeeds/:id(.:format)                            newsfeeds#update
                     PUT    /newsfeeds/:id(.:format)                            newsfeeds#update
                     DELETE /newsfeeds/:id(.:format)                            newsfeeds#destroy
                root GET    /                                                   newsfeeds#index
```

This is the CommentsController:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
        redirect_to newsfeed_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
end
end
```

Here is the NewsfeedsController:

```
class NewsfeedsController < ApplicationController

before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :destroy, :edit, :update]

def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

def show
    # before_action is taking care of all 4 i.e(sho,edit,update and destroy)..Keeping it DRY
end

def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
end

def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
        redirect_to newsfeed_path(@post)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end

private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content)
end

def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

end
```

end

in _form.html

```
<%= simple_form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]), url: newsfeed_comments_path(@post.id) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :content,label: false, placeholder: "write your comment here..." %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-custom' %>
<% end %>
```

I am getting this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing block): 1: <%= simple_form_for ([@post, 
@post.comments.build]), url: newsfeed_comments_path(@post.id) do |f| %> 2: 
<%= f.input :content,label: false, placeholder: "write your comment here..." 
%> 3: <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-custom' %> 4: <% end %>
```

Thanks for the support in advance.

Here is show.html where _form is being rendered,

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

    <div>

        <h3><%= @post.content %></h3>
        <p class=""><%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> ago </p>

    </div>

    <div>
        <h4>Comments:</h4>
        <p><%= render @post.comments %></p>

        <h4 class="reply-to-msg">Leave your Comment here..</h4>
        <%= render 'comments/form' %>

    </div>

    <div>
        <%= link_to "Back", root_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_newsfeed_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", newsfeed_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You Sure Master..?"} , class: "btn btn-danger" %>
    </div>

</div>
```

Routes here:

```
devise_for :users
resources :newsfeeds do
  resources :comments
end
root 'newsfeeds#index'
```

Comment: Could you please add a full text of the error

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing block):
    1: <%= simple_form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]), url: newsfeed_comments_path(@post.id) do |f| %>
    2:   <%= f.input :content,label: false, placeholder: "write your comment here..." %>
    3:   <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-custom' %>
    4: <% end %>

Comment: I am not using rails convention,
i have 3 model i.e user, post and comment
2 controller i.e. newsfeed_contoller and comment_controller

Comment: Please, add full code of your view, in which you render the `_form` partial. Maybe you're trying to render form partial inside another form?

Comment: yes i am rendring it on newsfeed show page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a brackets issue. You have a space between method name and brackets. Should be

```
<%= simple_form_for [@post, @post.comments.build], url: newsfeed_comments_path(@post.id) do |f| %>
```

or

```
<%= simple_form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], url: newsfeed_comments_path(@post.id)) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
First one works.
Caan you help me understanding why it is necessary to use url here?
@Vasilisa Thank you again

Comment: @AnshulEnbake, it's because of [record identification](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification). It figures out the path based on the record class. For some reason you're working with posts inside the NewsfeedsController, that's why you should specify url manually

Comment: @AnshulEnbake, what is in your routes? Maybe it would be better to use `resources :posts, path: 'newsfeeds'` and rename the controller according to rails conventions?

Comment: its my task not to use rails convention, and please take a look in,
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
here,
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
not oking but,
`@post = Post.find(params[:newsfeed_id])` <- working, even its not a column define in DB?
HOW?

Comment: Routes added above.

Comment: @AnshulEnbake, interesting task! `newsfeed_id` is not about column in DB, it is just identifier in route, it's how `resources` works. Read more [in guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)

Comment: can you please look into this.. @Vasilisa  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062410/i-am-trying-to-get-a-custom-json-in-rails-app-to-fetch-nested-user-data-and-thei

Comment: @RocKhalil Here it showing all the comment of associated post without any loop how? like we use each to showing all post but how come comments working here?