# I am trying to get a custom json in rails app to fetch nested user data and their post respectivelly but page is not displaying right content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, render

I have 3 model user, post and comment.
the user can have multiple post and comments.
I need to produce the JSON for last 50 post only.
 I am not using rails convention, so i have to write that in neewsfeed_controller.
Thank for the support.

class NewsfeedsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

```
def build
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    render json: {:event => @posts}
end


def data
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    render :partial => "newsfeeds/data.json"
end

private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content)
end

def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

end
```

end

In View: data.json.erb

```
 <%= res = {
  :posts => @posts.map do |post|

  end
} %>

<% res.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Routes:

```
get 'build' => 'newsfeeds#build'
get 'data' => 'newsfeeds#data', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

Form build i am getting data.
but i want custom json format from `data.json`,

## Response Format which i want :

```
[
  {
    "type": "Post",
    "content": "First post",
    "user": {
      "type": "User",
      "name": "Luke"
    },
    "comments": [
      {
        "type": "Comment",
        "user": {
          "type": "User",
          "name": "Leia"
        },
        "content": "First comment"
      },
      {
        "type": "Comment",
        "user": {
          "type": "User",
          "name": "Han"
        },
        "content": "Second comment"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "Post",
    "content": "Second post",
    "user": {
      "type": "User",
      "name": "Darth Vader"
    },
    "comments": [
      {
        "type": "Comment",
        "user": {
          "type": "User",
          "name": "Boba Fett"
        },
        "content": "Third comment"
      },
      {
        "type": "Comment",
        "user": {
          "type": "User",
          "name": "Jabba"
        },
        "content": "Fourth comment"
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Please guide.

Currently, I am not able to get that format.

Comment: Did you just omit posting the surrounding `<%= %>` in your `.erb` file or did you forget them in the original, too?

Comment: Hi, i have made changes in question and remove unecessary code.

Comment: Try switching `<%=` and `<%` in your template. The former is used to actually render the result of the Ruby code into the template while the latter is for just running arbitrary code.

Comment: giving blank page,
i need response like above mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to override the `to_json` in your models:

**app/models/post.rb**

```
def to_json
  return {
    type: 'Post',
    content: self.content,
    user: self.user ? self.user.to_json : nil,
    comments: self.comments.map(&:to_json)
  }
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
def to_json
  return {
    type: 'User',
    name: self.name
  }
end
```

**app/models/comment.rb**

```
def to_json
  return {
    type: 'Comment',
    content: self.content,
    user: self.user ? self.user.to_json : nil,
  }
end
```

Then in your controller, do something like:

```
def data
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    render json: @posts.map(&:to_json), status: :ok
end
```

Comment: hi,
there is no line break
 all coming lsingle line,

`[{"type":"Post","content":"ededed","user":{"type":"User","name":"aaa@aaa.aaa"},"comments":[]},{"type":"Post","content":"123sss","user":{"type":"User","name":"sss@sss.sss"},"comments":[{"type":"Comment","content":"werfefd","user":{"type":"User","name":"aaa@aaa.aaa"}}]},{"type":"Post","content":"aesrdtasdfdgfhjrdtuiuihkjhgfd","user":{"type":"User","name":"aaa@aaa.aaa"},"comments":[{"comments":[]}]`

Comment: @AnshulEnbake what ? what is intentinging ?

Comment: I meant the same line and thanks for the support. please guide how to make that structure @RocKhalil

Comment: @AnshulEnbake basically, JSON response should be as tiny as it can be; so this is the optimal solution. If you want to see it prettified, use any online tool to prettify it - I personally use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu

Comment: Hi @RocKhalil how can i restrict json response data for only first 50 post.

Comment: @AnshulEnbake you'll have to add a `limit` to your `@posts`; `@posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").limit(50)`; you can use pagination gems or create your own using `limit` and `offset`. btw, if you think my comments was valid, please mark it as the answer and upvote it :-) this is the basic usage of stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks, mate :) can't upvote as a newbie here. Stack overflow Declining my request for upvote.

Comment: @AnshulEnbake haha no worries :-) glad I was able to help :-D